# Quantstrat Naming of accounts and portfolios

Tags: r, quantstrat

I'm relatively new to R, and very new to quantstrat/blotter. In all of the examples I've seen, a string is loaded into a porfolio and account (portfolio.st, account.st). 
What is the purpose of this? I'm not saving information into that string, and usually remove `rm.strat` (portfolio.st) in order to load another portfolio. Perhaps I don't quite understand how the account and portfolio objects work.

example:

```
portfolio.st <- "Port.Luxor.Stop.Loss" #Why load a string here? Why not just call the portfolio "portfolio.SL"?
account.st <- "Acct.Luxor.Stop.Loss"
strategy.st <- "Strat.Luxor.Stop.Loss"

rm.strat(portfolio.st)
rm.strat(account.st)

initPortf(name = portfolio.st,
      symbols = symbols,
      initDate = init_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I highly recommend you going through [Guy Yollin](https://4310b1a9-a-a8fb2076-s-sites.googlegroups.com/a/r-programming.org/home/files/quantstrat.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7cqqIMHC5Z7MyAYOV12RFT47_WSSeOyyaSM0m75HDFtFvGm0ah_iebwP6v8ikFPyoQ4n3NeBiNiX7DnMXeNca4P3aA6wJCe5F9nJW7lJbflct4azl0Yy5m2EaZapJ2DdOvAWTM6KRMSkyNW1puaMcD-S0RJwvNvkhe0tF9MiLzDbHHDiEoF-E3D-8LqgKmyRrwjV0FbW1eRCNFKPsVuM9pRfPCpiOg%3D%3D&attredirects=0)'s notes on quantstrat. Then I highly recommend you adding `browser()` to every functions in the quantstrat library. Then you will start to see how portfolio.st, account.st and strategy.st are contributing to the script.

I learned all of this after 6 months of getting comfortable with R.

First of all run the whole code. Then in the terminal type `.strategy$` and you will start seeing your strategy names. Whenever you add an indicator or signal or rules, you will find your environment storing all of that.

Unfortunately, its hard to explain environment when you are really new to R and quantstrat. Trust me, I have been there. Always feel free to shoot me a message if you want me to explain something here.

Answer (score 0):

> `portfolio.st <- "Port.Luxor.Stop.Loss" #Why load a string here? Why not just call the portfolio "portfolio.SL"?`

You can call it whatever you'd like, but you have to call it something. The way `quantstrat` and `blotter` are structured, you're creating an object with attributes that will be stored in a separate environment. The examples you're reading are structured with the names at the top to make it easier to find them. The choice of name (`"Port.Luxor.Stop.Loss"` vs `"portfolio.SL"`), again, is entirely up to you, but it should be meaningful for you and anyone you're working with (including your future self).

Comment: Thanks Dan.

I think the *root cause* of my lack of understanding is I don't understand the structure of quantstrat. 
Could you explain how it's storing the object in another environment? 
Is that other environment the strategy.st? 
Do you have any resource where I can explore for myself (Abridged, so I'm not just reading the R-Forge documentation)?

Comment: `quantstrat` and `blotter` do not use typical R programming methods, so it can be hard to understand it right off if you're new at it. If your question is: why do I have to give `portfolio.st` a character vector at the top of my code, i think i've answered that for you (you don't). If you want to learn more about environments, Hadley Wickham's advanced R book has [a good chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html). That might prove helpful. You can use some of what you learn there to understand the quantstrat source and explore the `.strategy` and .`blotter` environments.